# onclick inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am working on a project and in this project I got the following code inside a .js file.

```
    // continue button (jump to next field)
    this.ctrlContinue = createElement( 'button', { cName : 'fs-continue', inner : 'Continue', appendTo : this.ctrls } );
    this._showCtrl( this.ctrlContinue );
```

I need to add `onclick="setBrowserFrameSource(); return false;"` to the above code. I have tried:

`cName : 'fs-continue' . 'onclick="setBrowserFrameSource(); return false;"',` But this did not work!

Thanks for helping.

Here some more code as asked in the comments:

```
    /**
 * addControls function
 * create and insert the structure for the controls
 */
FForm.prototype._addControls = function() {
    // main controls wrapper
    this.ctrls = createElement( 'div', { cName : 'fs-controls', appendTo : this.el } );
```

Thanks to the answer from Rafail Akhmetshin I have changed the code to the following:

```
        this.ctrlContinue = createElement( 'button', { cName : 'fs-continue', inner : 'Continue', appendTo : this.ctrls } );
    this.ctrlContinue.onclick = function () {
        console.log('test');
    };      
    this._showCtrl( this.ctrlContinue );
```

Now my instinct says I need to do something with this `console.log('test');`
But what? Do I need to change this into `setBrowserFrameSource(); return false;` or should I add the code into the original function?

Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: provide a code of `createElement` function

Comment: What is `createElement`?

Comment: Which JavaScript framework is used in your project? I'd try `cName: 'fsContinue', onclick: '...', ` (comma, not dot).

Comment: it's a function in document object : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: @KirillPisarev, edited my comment, yet you could do `'onclic'`: '...'` too

Comment: @MohamedA. it's not native function, and only `window` properties are global (can be called withount `window.`)

Comment: @OlegGrenrus I have tried the comma instead of the dot. But it is not working. It is now disregarding all the code in the js file.

Comment: All the information in the comments is way above my head. native global document object no clue what it all means. I am trying to learn as quick as I can by trial and error. But most of the time I learn from complete codes. Because somehow I can see the logic. Do not see this message as a negetive message. I just wanted to let everyone know that they are not commenting to an IT Guru but more to a rookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
this.ctrlContinue.onclick = function () {
    // your code here.
};
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I only have one problem I have no idea how to implement your code. It is all new for me.

Comment: put it after element is created. after `createElement()` is called

Comment: `  this.ctrlContinue = createElement( 'button', { cName : 'fs-continue', inner : 'Continue', appendTo : this.ctrls } );
  this.ctrlContinue.onclick = function () {
      console.log('test');
  };  
  this._showCtrl( this.ctrlContinue );`

What should I write by console.log

Comment: I am sorry. instead of `console.log('test');` you should write your code. javascript logic that should be executed when element, you created, is clicked.

Comment: So that is the original code not `setBrowserFrameSource(); return false;`

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! It is working now. I added the original code and it is doing its thing. Thank you very much.